# Should I be worried about a ReDOS attack?

Tags: php, security

Can the following code be use to [ReDOS](http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?14,31355,31355) attack my site?

Or will it just be ended when the `max_execution_time` is exceeded or is it a problem of the past?

I use the following code to validate emailaddresses on my sites (by [Douglas Lovell](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585?page=0,3)):

```
function validate_email($email)
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
   } else {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
      {
         // local part starts or ends with '.'
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
      {
         // local part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
      {
         // character not valid in domain part
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
      {
         // domain part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/', str_replace("\\\\","",$local))) {
         // character not valid in local part unless
         // local part is quoted
         if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/', str_replace("\\\\","",$local))) {
            $isValid = false;
         }
      }
      if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
      {
         // domain not found in DNS
         $isValid = false;
      }
   }

   return $isValid;
}
```

Comment: It looks somewhat like what you find here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585?page=0,3

Comment: @Jared Farrish  and how does that make it immune to ReDOS?

Comment: @Rook - [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8235707/revisions) at the line right above the code block. `;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the regular expressions you're using here have behavior that'd be prone to excessive runtime.

Judging from the name, however, `checkdnsrr()` might take a while if the domain's nameservers are unresponsive. Make sure it has a sane timeout.